# Need to add a port number in server.xml and need another localhost

Tags: java, tomcat

I have 2 java projects. One is running in `localhost:8080` and I want to run another project in any other port. I found the port number `8082` is available to use.

This is already available in server.xml in apache-tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8080" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
```

Should I add another connector like this and restart the server?

```
<Connector port="8082" redirectPort="8444" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
```

And give in the browser `localhost:8082/newprojectname`?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to ask our permission to try things to see if they work or not.

Comment: Yes I tried and it didnt work.When I restarted the server and gave localhost:8082/newprojectname it didn't show up in the browser.

Comment: Are you using two different Tomcats or just a single Tomcat? If one, why would you want to have a second HTTP connector? That is nonsense. Feels like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your second project on a different port number (while the first project is still available on port 8080), you will have to install a second Tomcat.

Consider to deploy your second project together with the first one into your existing Tomcat server. You can then access both on localhost at port 8080 - just with different paths. The path is determined by the directory name of the deployed project in the `webapps` folder of your Tomcat.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I can try to install another tomcat in eclipse and run the project separately. But installing the 2 projects in 8080 will not work as one is already listening to it. I tried giving localhost:8080/project1-it shows up,localhost:8080/project2 -it says unable to connect.